# Inline comment in ansible jinja2 template

Tags: ansible, jinja2

My docker `.env` file is created from a jinja2 template. I'm using `{# ... #}` for [comments](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#comments).

It has this:

```
FOO={{BAR}}        {# blah blah blah #}
SOMETHING=2
```

I expect it to render:

```
FOO=1
SOMETHING=2
```

But it actually renders:

```
FOO=1    SOMETHING=2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update for 2021 (version 3.0.x)

---

### Use plus sign (+) in tag

As @mdaniel pointed out, there are a few ways to adjust Jinja2's whitespace behavior, but a new option has appeared in [3.0.x's documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#whitespace-control) that I believe is easiest way to solve the problem:

> ... you can manually disable the trim_blocks behavior by
> putting a plus sign (+) at the end of a block:
>
> ```
> <div>
>   {% if something +%}
>     yay
>   {% endif %}
> </div>
> ```

Therefore, your specific problem should be easily solved by the insertion of a single plus symbol:

```
FOO={{BAR}}        {# blah blah blah +#}
SOMETHING=2
```

And if you want to remove the whitespace which would appear between the variable and the comment, explicitly remove it with a minus symbol:

```
FOO={{BAR}}        {#- blah blah blah +#}
SOMETHING=2
```

---

### Use `trim_blocks` parameter

Since this question tags Ansible, I should point out that you can also modify the behavior by setting the `trim_blocks` parameter of the [`ansible.builtin.template` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html). This has been part of Ansible since version 2.4. The default is `yes`, but you can set it to `no` to achieve the desired result.

---

Hopefully this will help other people who find this question seeking a similar solution.

Answer (score 2):

Jinja2 strips trailing newlines after blocks, [as described in the fine manual](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#whitespace-control)

You can influence that behavior in at least 3 ways:

1. Don't use end-of-line comments (since they will end with `#}\n` and thus jinja2 will eat the `\n`)
2. Force the character after the jinja2 block to be a non-newline character (such as `#} \n`, although that will make git and some editors mad, since it is considered trailing whitespace
3. If this is happening in a `template:` context, you can turn off [`trim_blocks: no`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#parameter-trim_blocks); in certain contexts, you can do that inside the template itself, too, via a `#jinja2:trim_blocks:False` header in the template, as described by that `template:` documentation page

Comment: I couldn't find the part that explains the "header in the template" process, but I tried it and it worked - thanks.

Comment: I can't link to the bottom of the html page, but I can link [to its source code](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.10.7/lib/ansible/plugins/doc_fragments/template_common.py#L106-L109) and [the underlying python source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.10.7/lib/ansible/template/__init__.py#L1017-L1018)